Prevent SwiftUI navigationBar to automatically adjust/match background to adjacent element
I have a flight detail view (destination from a root navigation view) with a top bar that shows relative time to relevant times around said flight. This top bar is the first subview that sits at the very top of the detail view's body. But when it does, the toolbar/navigationbar background is automatically matched to this top bar's background, which may be a neat built in feature but not in this case...
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        StatusView().padding(.top, 1) // <-- "Solves" it but don't want this gap
        FlightCardView()
        GateInfoView()
        // and so on
    }
    .navigationTitle(listItem.flightNo) // Not really necessary, overridden by .principal
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("SK").fontWeight(.light)
                    Text(listItem.flightNo).fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .font(.system(size:18))
                Text(formatDateString(date: rosterItem.date, to: "EEEE d"))
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
        }
    }
    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) // Or color variants not working
}


First two screenshots show the subview in question at the very top of the body, causing the navigationbar to match the color. If I give a top padding of 1 to this subview, the navigationbar gets its default translucent background (last screenshot) but not if the subview is exactly adjacent to it. I obviously don't want that 1px gap.
I've already tried .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) modifier without any success. As per a similar post, I've also applied the following init() to the parent view (from where this detail view is navigated from) but without luck.
init() {
        let standardAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        standardAppearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial) // I do NOT want the opaque background
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standardAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = standardAppearance
    }

Anyone knows how to prevent the navigationbar to match its background to adjacent elements when they are not yet "under" the NavBar?

The effect you are seeing is a translucent Material background when the screen content scrolls up behind the top region.
To show a solid color instead, it works for me when .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) is changed to a color, or to some other ShapeStyle such as .background.
Here is a standalone example to show it working:
NavigationStack {
    ScrollView {
        Color.blue
            .frame(height: 250)
            .overlay(Text("StatusView"))
        Color.pink
            .frame(height: 400)
            .overlay(Text("FlightCardView"))
        Color.green
            .frame(height: 400)
            .overlay(Text("GateInfoView"))
        // and so on
    }
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
            VStack {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("SK").fontWeight(.light)
                    Text("123").fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .font(.system(size:18))
                Text("Friday 12 April")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
    // comment out to see the default Material background
    .toolbarBackground(.background, for: .navigationBar)
}


If you are not able to get it to work in the context of your code, please try to provide a complete working example that allows the problem to be reproduced.

Yes, it's within a NavigationStack from its parent view like you've simplified. This view is not "tall" enough like yours though (yet, could be later). I get that the Material background spreads out like that when elements scroll behind it, but this is just edge to edge directly below it. It seems the translucency present the background like this when my colored element is "just about to get beneath" even though technically it's not. I want to keep the translucency (not solid/opaque) but not until the element is actually behind...

@ScoobyDooku If you comment out the .toolbarBackground from the example in this answer then you will see that it behaves exactly as you want it to. So it would really help, if you could provide a working example to show it not working. Is it possible that you are setting a vertical offset somewhere? If so, try it without.
